# Any way to empty JaversRepository?

Tags: javers

During my implementation of JaVers in my microservice, i've been doing tests with the commits, to get familiarized with JaVers. However, now i configued it with a MongoRepository, and it has brought me all the commits from the JaVers repository i do not need. There is any way to empty that from JaVers repository (i guess it is stored there always)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `clean()` method in `MongoRepository` but it's package private.

```
void clean(){
    snapshotsCollection().deleteMany(new Document());
    headCollection().deleteMany(new Document());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot ! Great work with javers!